# Adding a figure to footnote as a float with footnote text wrapping around it

Tags: floats, footnotes, wrapfigure

I'm trying to do this with the wrap fig package. But the figure float does not rearrange dynamically as I change the text in my document hence the layout, going above page number, out of the margin, etc.... Is there to tell tex to position the float accordingly to the changing environment... Hope I'm clear, and thanks!

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
    \graphicspath{/Users/haimbook/Desktop/}
    \begin{document}

     This is a foot note \footnote{
     \blindtext

     \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{8cm} % 15cm is usually too wide to have the figure next     to text
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{figure}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide code that shows your problem. I tried adding two `\blindtext` before `This is ...` and another just before `\end{document}` and all looked good to me, just as your original MWE did.

Comment: what do you want to change about the output shown?

Comment: While footnotes can break across pages, wrapfig cannot.  Worse, since it is overlaid onto the page, no space is reserved.  I believe you could put the wrapfigure and the text together inside a minipage, but the whole thing would not break then.

Comment: Understood. Do you see a way then to obtain what I would like to obtain? With a different package? Thanks

Comment: You could format a footnote to fit the page, but it will not be automatic.  Footnotes are formatted when they are created and copied into \footins (savebox).  Page breaking uses \vsplit on \footins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to start wrapfigure in the middle of a paragraph in order to fit the footnote to the page,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
%\graphicspath{/Users/haimbook/Desktop/}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{25\baselineskip}

 This is a foot note \footnote{%
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
 Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullam-
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{8cm} % 15cm is usually too wide to have the figure next     to text
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
corper.  felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat
pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent
in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique
neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi
sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus
tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.   

\lipsum[1]}% end of footnote

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```